# How to access the links variable from a template?

Tags: 7, navigation

I have created a views template for a block and I would like to insert the list of links that normally appears at the bottom of teasers and/or pages (the $links variable) into the template like it is done in `page.tpl.php`.

However I can't find how to get this information given a node's id.

How do I accomplish this? Is there a Drupal 7 command that accomplishes this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to this problem. You need to do the following in your template:

```
<?php $node = node_load($fields['nid']->raw);
global $language;
node_build_content($node, 'full', $language->language);
if (!empty($node->content['links'])): ?>
    <div class="links">
      <?php print render($node->content['links']); ?>
    </div> <!-- /links -->
<?php endif; ?>
```